# /s regex is not finding all whitespace in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

> str => "The problem is that good food can be extremely
>   expensive...but it doesn't have to be. \n Thrive Market is like Costco for everything healthy - an online shopping club offering the best brands and groceries at 25-50% off"

I then do `str.gsub(/\s/, " _ ")` and I get:

> The _ problem _ is _ that _ good _ food _ can _ be _ extremely _ expensive...but _ it _ doesn't _ have _ to _ be. _ Thrive Market is like Costco for everything healthy - an online shopping club offering the best brands and groceries at 25-50% off

The whitespace in the second sentence is untouched.  Any ideas?

Edit: Here is a link to the text on pastebin http://pastebin.com/LjiybnrZ .  Try it in rubular.

Comment: Use `multiline` flag, to match across line-breaks.

Comment: Please share some code to reproduce the issue. [Your code works fine](https://ideone.com/Pp956A).

Comment: I think stack overflow is fixing the problem when it saves the text, try it with the raw text from pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexp metacharacter `\s` doesn't match [non-breaking whitepaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), because it behaves like `/[^ \t\r\n\f]/`.

Use this instead:

```
str.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, ' _ ')
```

Read more about that in the [Docs for `Regexp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add special flag to `gsub`, something like this `str.gsub(/\s/m, " _ ")`

Comment: Good thought!  Unfortunately it's producing the same results

Comment: Edited question with link to text to try out.

Comment: Ruby's multiline mode is the same as other flavors' single-line or DOTALL modes.  All it does is let the dot match line-separator characters. There are no dots in the OP's regex.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out using http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Basically the ones that convert are `U+0020 : SPACE` and the ones that don't are  `U+00A0 : NO-BREAK SPACE`.

I don't know why ruby `\s` doesn't pick it up.